# Remove duplicate and merge inner dictionary items from a list in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as following

```
[
{
    "user": [
        "jon"
    ], 
    "email": "jon123@email.com"
}, 
{
    "user": [
        "mike"
    ], 
    "email": "mike456@email.com"
}, 
{
    "user": [
        "J Jon", 
        "Jonathan"
    ], 
    "email": "jon123@email.com"
}, 
{
    "user": [
        "taylor"
    ], 
    "email": "taylor789@email.com"
}, 
{
    "user": [
        "me_mike"
    ], 
    "email": "mike456@email.com"
}
]
```

I want to merge two list items (as a dictionary) if those two items appears to have same `email` but different values in a `user` list inside the dictionary. How to obtain the result as following from the list shown above in python.

```
[
{
    "user": [
        "jon",
        "J Jon", 
        "Jonathan"
    ], 
    "email": "jon123@email.com"
}, 
{
    "user": [
        "mike",
        "me_mike"
    ], 
    "email": "mike456@email.com"
},  
{
    "user": [
        "taylor"
    ], 
    "email": "taylor789@email.com"
}     
]
```

Comment: "How to obtain the result as following from the list shown above in python." A good way is to actually try.

Comment: Try using a dictionary where the key is the user email and the value is a user list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dictionary in my_list:
    actual_email = dictionary.get('email')
    for dictionary_search in my_list:
        if dictionary != dictionary_search and actual_email == dictionary_search.get('email'):
            users = dictionary_search.get('user')
            for user in users:
                dictionary.get('user', []).append(user)
            my_list.remove(dictionary_search)
print(my_list)
```

Where my_list is your json list

Comment: Your code indentation is not correct

Comment: Copy paste sorry. I updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
a = ... # the json list
d = {}
for i in a:
    d.setdefault(i['email'], []).extend(i['user'])

print [{'user' : v, 'email' : k} for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: I wrote the exact same code down to the comas and spaces

Comment: I wrote this code also, but I did not know about the method called setdefault. So my code was a little longer than this. Thanks I learned a new method by reading your code.

Comment: Why not using a `defaultdict(list)` and avoid the `setdefault` and `extend` methods?

Comment: @VMRuiz, yes could've used `defaultdict()` but it didn't occurred to me at that time. :P